# cloud DLP - sample / how to , convert a local file (Linux) to a secure CSV file

Tags: pip, cloud, google-cloud-dlp

Do I really need a Google Cloud box to run DLP conversion for a local file before up-load to a Google Cloud bigquery box?

I just want to convert a csv file to a secure data protective file format ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the DLP product is an API in the cloud.

You can use [gCloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) similar to the example below - though this will only do simple redaction and based in infoType findings, not record transforms (apply transform to a whole column).  For the full set of features, you would stream in as a table into the [Content.deidentify](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.content/deidentify)

[image]

Comment: So this example for 2 columns at test.csv file; no need any Cloud DB connection. Can you post your test.csv ?

Comment: The test.csv was just an example one to illustrate how you could accomplish this.